# Why is EF inserting new data for entities that I'm not specifying?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I'm going to chunk this down to as simple a case as I can, but this happens for everything.

I'm basing most of my data model POCO objects on a BaseDataObject defined as follows:

```
public class BaseDataObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

My code-first data model has a `Client` object:

```
public class Client : BaseDataObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Subcategory { get; set; }
}
```

The `Category` object is pretty simple:

```
public class Category : BaseDataObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The required `Id` property exists in the inherited `BaseDataObject`.

To add entities, I'm using the following repo:

```
public class DataRepository<TModel, TContext>
    where TModel : BaseDataObject
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    public int AddItem(T item)
    {
        using (var db = (TContext)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TContext)))
        {
            db.Set<T>().Add(item);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    // These are important as well.
    public List<T> ListItems(int pageNumber = 0)
    {
        using (var db = (TContext)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TContext)))
        {
            // Deleted property is also included in BaseDataObject.
            return db.Set<T>().Where(x => !x.Deleted).OrderBy(x => x.Id).Skip(10 * pageNumber).ToList();
    }

    public T GetSingleItem(int id)
    {
        using (var db = (TContext)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TContext)))
        {
            return db.Set<T>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id && !x.Deleted);
        }
    }
}
```

This adds a new client perfectly fine, but there's something weird about my data model here that's causing Entity Framework to also add 2 new Categories every time I add a client based on which categories I'm selecting on my form.

Here's my form's code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        try
        {
            BindDropDownList<Category>(CategoryList);
            BindDropDownList<Category>(SubcategoryList);
        }
        // Error handling things
    }
}

private void BindDropDownList<TModel>(DropDownList control) where TModel : BaseDataObject
{
    var repo = new DataRepository<TModel, ApplicationDbContext>();
    control.DataSource = repo.ListItems();
    control.DataTextField = "Name";
    control.DataValueField = "Id";
    control.DataBind();
    control.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Please select --", "0"));
}
private TModel GetDropDownListSelection<TModel>(DropDownList control) where TModel : BaseDataObject
{
    var repo = new DataRepository<TModel, ApplicationDbContext>();
    int.TryParse(control.SelectedItem.Value, out int selectedItemId);
    return repo.GetSingleItem(selectedItemId);
}

protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var repo = new DataRepository<Client, ApplicationDbContext();

        var selectedCategory = GetDropDownListSelection<Category>(CategoryList);
        var selectedSubcategory = GetDropDownListSelection<Category>(SubcategoryList);
        var name = NameTextBox.Text;

        var client = new Client
        {
            Name = name,
            Category = selectedCategory,
            Subcategory = selectedSubcategory
        };

        repo.AddItem(client);
    }
    // Error handling things
}
```

Unless there's something wrong with the way I'm creating the relationship here (using the virtual keyword or something maybe) then I can't see any reason why this would add new Categories to the database as duplicates of existing ones based on the selections I make in the drop down lists.

Why is this happening? What have I got wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DbSet<T>.Add` method cascades recursively to navigation properties which are not currently tracked by the context and marks them as `Added`. So when you do

```
db.Set<T>().Add(item);
```

it actually marks both `Client` class referenced `Category` entities as `Added`, hence `SaveChanges` inserts two new duplicate `Category` records.

The usual solution is to tell EF that entities are existing by attaching them to the context in advance. For instance, if you replace `repo.AddItem(client);` with

```
using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    if (client.Category != null) db.Set<Category>().Attach(client.Category);
    if (client.Subcategory != null) db.Set<Category>().Attach(client.Subcategory);
    db.Set<Client>().Add(item);
    db.SaveChanges();    
}
```

everything will be fine.

The problem is that you use generic repository implementation which does not provide you the necessary control. But that's your design decision issue, not EF. The above is EF intended way to handle such operation. How you can fit it into your design is up to you (I personally would eliminate the generic repository anti-pattern and use directly the db context).

Comment: I was super proud of the generic repo implementation since its literally the first time I'm using generics but it really seems to be more of a hindrance since I'm moving everything into a more tailored repo anyway

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to judge from your listing because no FK mappings are included nor the base model details are provided.

However, it would appear that the `Category` that you assigned to `client` does not have PK set, and (most likely) only has the Name set, and you have no unique IX on that.

So EF has no reasonable way to work out that this is the right category.

One way to sort it is

```
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var repo = new DataRepository<Client, ApplicationDbContext>();

        var selectedCategory = GetDropDownListSelection<Category>(CategoryList);
        var selectedSubcategory = GetDropDownListSelection<Category>(SubcategoryList);
        var name = NameTextBox.Text;

        var client = new Client
        {
            Name = name,
            // either
            Category = new DataRepository<Category , ApplicationDbContext>().GetSingleItem(selectedCategory.id),
            // or, easier (assuming you have FK properties defined on the model)
            CategoryId = selectedCategory.Id,
            // repeat as needed
            Subcategory = selectedSubcategory
        };

        repo.AddItem(client);
    }
    // Error handling things
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Because Category inherits from the BaseDataObject, it does get built with the Id value which EF assigns as the Primary Key and the database diagram I'm looking at does show the relationship so I'm still not sure what's going on.